# What are the main open source two way sync frameworks available natively on ubuntu, which sync via "diff merging"?

Tags: 14.04, sync, open-source, diff

So again, the software needs to be:

1. **Open Source** - so I can program with it.
2. **Sync Two Ways** - so two or more users can have simultaneous control over one file, unlike Rsync which syncs only one way.
3. **Available naively on ubuntu** - because I do not want to deal with wine or google docs.
4. **Syncs via a diff merge** - because this is quicker than replacing the entire file.

**My specific use case:**

I need to use this software as a backend to a project I am creating for collaborative editing. This project will be a Plugin for the Ubuntu SDK. While I have heard of projects such as Google Wave, and Gobby; these are not solutions for what I am trying to accomplish. However; if you are aware of the underlying technology they are utilizing, I would be interested to hear what they used.

Otherwise; I just want to know what is available on Ubuntu, so I can do my research from there.

Edit:

Just to clarify, Unison is an example of a program I am looking for.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: Can you specify better what do you mean for _"Sync Two Ways - so two or more users can have simultaneous control over one file, unlike Rsync which syncs only one way."_ ? Do you search something like git or a [revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software)?

Comment: @Hastur Good Question. Two way sync, I mean by this: http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188061/Unison-Makes-Two-Way-File-Sync-Simple | Also; Git is an option I am looking into, despite it using delta compression rather than merging diffs. Any suggestions like git, are welcome.